# .docx file edited in TextEdit once, lost all footnotes

Tags: ms-office, textedit

I used **TextEdit** to quickly add two sentences in my **.docx** file. Before I could react, the file was *overwritten* and I could not get the previous version of this file, as it was on my USB key. Fortunately I did not lose all formatting, but unfortunately **ALL** footnotes (that were added beforehand in Word) have been deleted and I do not see them in Word on Windows. Is there an explanation for this incident and recovery plan for this? I am perfectly aware of differences of formats used by **TextEdit** and **Office**.

Comment: You said, "_I am perfectly aware of differences of formats used by **TextEdit** and **Office**._" however your actions seem to contradict that! Was the .docx file not Locked when you opened it and when you went  to edited it asked, "Are you sure you want to modify the document in place?" then warned "Modifying the document in place might cause you to lose some of the original formatting.  Would you like to duplicate the document first?"? I was when I tried. If you don't have a backup, which you always should have, then your out of luck. TextEdit does not fully support the .docx file standard.

Comment: Did you really not get the warning mentioned by user3439894?  It certainly comes up for me when the doc is on the harddrive desktop.  I did not test using a usb key.

Comment: As I stated before, I was unable to stop it before it autosaved. Normally on my personal Mac above mentioned warning would be shown and I would react it. But I think on this particular Mac these warnings were turned off.

Aside of that I wanted to export it as another file or even save it as other copy to leave main file unmodified. That's why I am asking about it here.